# Cant use boost in xCode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

When I am trying to use the boost library in xCode, i keep getting an error.
I have linked the header and link library like the tutorials say, but i am still getting an error

```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>            // std::string
> #include <sstream>           // std::stringstream
> #include <initializer_list>
> #include <vector>
> #include <boost/type_index.hpp>
> using std::cout;
> using std::endl;
```

at the boost index, my compiler says "'boost/type_index.hpp' file not found" when I try building..

How do i fix this?

Comment: How can you link header ? You need to specify the header search path in Xcode.

Comment: I have the path specified

Answer (score 3):

In your Xcode project build settings, you must ensure you find/choose it in the the header search paths. (eg `/usr/local/boost_1_60_0/include/`)

Comment: So after the /include, I add the path to the library?

Comment: No, click the project settings in Xcode, then in the build settings add the path to yours where it says `header search paths`

Comment: I already did so and I am still getting these errors. That’s why I asked this question, because I followed instructions by adding the header and library to my boost that I installed. I am still getting the same error